# Jabber.NET SASL Exception / Auth Error

Tags: c#, .net, xmpp, openfire

I use **Jabber.NET** to connect to an **OpenFire** Server. The clients are giving me a strange exception *sometimes* (but most of the time): `jabber.connection.sasl.SASLException: Hash ist im angegebenen Status nicht gültig`, which is a german message stating that the hash is invalid for the designated status. *Sometimes* (yes, I know, but I can't influence) it, I also get the Exception `jabber.connection.sasl.SASLException: Das SafeHandle wurde geschlossen`, which means that the SafeHandle has been closed.

I tried turning on an off all possible security settings, but it all has no effect. This is how I connect:

```
    private JabberClient _jabberClient = null;
    public JabberClient XmppClient
    {
        get
        {
            if (_jabberClient == null)
                _jabberClient = new JabberClient();
            return _jabberClient;
        }
    }

    // double checked: username and password are correct, servername is existing URL
    public login(username,password,servername)
    {
        var jid = new JID(username, serverName, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        bedrock.net.AsyncSocket.UntrustedRootOK = true;
        XmppClient.RequiresSASL = false; // --> this seems to have no effect at all
        //XmppClient[Options.SASL_MECHANISMS] = MechanismType.PLAIN; // setting this throws a NotImplementedException!!!
        XmppClient.SSL = false;
        XmppClient.AutoPresence = true;
        XmppClient.AutoReconnect = 3.0f;
        XmppClient.AutoLogin = true;
        XmppClient.AutoStartTLS = true;
        XmppClient.AutoStartCompression = false;
        XmppClient.User = jid.User;
        XmppClient.Password = password;
        XmppClient.Resource = jid.Resource;
        XmppClient.Server = serverName;
        XmppClient.NetworkHost = serverName;

        XmppClient.OnMessage += new MessageHandler(JabberClient_OnMessage);
        XmppClient.OnDisconnect += new bedrock.ObjectHandler(JabberClient_OnDisconnect);
        XmppClient.OnError += new bedrock.ExceptionHandler(JabberClient_OnError);
        XmppClient.OnAuthError += new jabber.protocol.ProtocolHandler(JabberClient_OnAuthError);
        XmppClient.OnAuthenticate += new bedrock.ObjectHandler(XmppClient_OnAuthenticate);
        XmppClient.OnInvalidCertificate += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(XmppClient_OnInvalidCertificate);
        XmppClient.OnWriteText += new bedrock.TextHandler(XmppClient_OnWriteText);
    }
```

How can I resolve the issue? What might circumvent it? The only possibility I have right now is to authenticate a lot of times, until it luckily works, but that can take some time and I don't want to resort to that.

EDIT: The answer below got me the answer: it's as simple as identifying the exceptions and calling `connect()` again. Why the library doesn't do this automatically is a riddle for me, also I don't get why it uses SASL when it's deactivated, but well. Hacked, works. Thanks!

Comment: The library doesn't reconnect here because it's really unlikely that a server would act this way.  Authentication should either work or not, it shouldn't be unpredictable.  Reconnecting blindly here can lead to an infinite loop, with no chance for the user to correct their authentication information.  Furthermore, ALWAYS check for error type `conflict` before reconnecting, to avoid writing the dueling-JID bug.  Again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the problem, but here's my working code. Hope it helps.

```
    private JabberClient _client;
    private JabberClient client
    {
        get {
            if (_client == null)
            {
                _client = new JabberClient();
                ConfigureClient(_client);
            }
            return _client; 
        }
        set
        {
            _client = value;
            RegisterOnEvents(_client);
        }
    }      

    public MiddleMan()
    {
        jabber.connection.ConferenceManager c = new jabber.connection.ConferenceManager();

        client = new JabberClient();

        ConfigureClient(client);
    }  

    private void ConfigureClient(JabberClient jc)
    {
        JID jid = new JID(LoginInformation.UserName);

        jc.User = jid.User;
        jc.Server = jid.Server;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(LoginInformation.NetworkHost))
        {
            jc.NetworkHost = LoginInformation.NetworkHost;
        }
        jc.Port = 5222;
        jc.AutoReconnect = 3f;
        jc.AutoLogin = true;
        jc.AutoPresence = true;
        jc.Resource = LoginInformation.Resource;
        jc.Password = LoginInformation.Password;
        jc.KeepAlive = 10;
    }

    private void RegisterOnEvents(JabberClient jc)
    {
        //Messaging
        //jc.OnMessage += new MessageHandler(OnMessageReceived);

        //Login
        jc.OnLoginRequired += (sender) =>
        {
           //code
        };

        jc.OnAuthenticate += (sender) =>
        {
            //code
        };

        jc.OnAuthError += (sender, rp) =>
        {
            //code
            this.Connect();
        };

        //Connection
        jc.OnConnect += (sender, stream) =>
        {
            //code
        };

        jc.OnDisconnect += (sender) =>
        {
            //code
            this.Connect();
        };

        jc.OnError += (sender, ex) =>
        {
            //code
            this.Connect();
        };

        //jc.OnPresence += new PresenceHandler(OnPresence);
    }
```